# Amplify with Graph QL how to query a related object

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, graphql

I'm learning how to use Amplify to deploy an AWS application.

I have a question about relations using graphql. I'm simply following along the documentation's tutorial. I generated the sample schema about blogs and posts here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql?sdk=angular

I'd like to know how to make a bit more of a complicated query than "find all".

Specifically: I can find all of the Posts like so:

```
import { APIService } from '../API.service';

export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private apiService: APIService) { }

@Input()
blog: any;

posts: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.ListPosts().then((evt) => {
      this.posts = evt.items;
    });
}
}
```

The code that's in the ngOnInit() function is fine for listing all of the posts ever. But how do I find a post by blog id?

The graphhql schema is as follows, which is just part of the tutorial in the link posted above:

```
type Blog @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
}
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  blog: Blog @connection(name: "BlogPosts")
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComments")
}
```

In the generated code, I see crud operations for these, but not for the "connections". How do I find all of the posts for a particular blog?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had a list of blogs but that list of blogs didn't have the posts within each blog item.

So on the "blogs component" where I have one blog, and I want to list the posts, I had to query the blog by id (which was provided in the blog list, and the query which is pre-compiled by amplify). The queried blog-by-id contains the populated posts.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  blog: Blog;

  posts: Array<Post>;

  constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.apiService.GetBlog(this.blog.id).then((blog) => {
      this.posts = blog.posts.items;
    });

  }

}
```